# Magento 2.4: PayPal NVP gateway errors: The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts

Tags: magento2, paypal

I am getting this error on paypal :

PayPal NVP gateway errors: The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts (#10413: Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details)

Can any one help me?

Answer (score 0):

Override file: **module-paypal/Model/Apiu/Nvp.php** in your custom module

Inside function `callSetExpressCheckout()`

add before **`$response = $this->call(self::SET_EXPRESS_CHECKOUT, $request);`**

**Add below code:**

```
$TAXAMT = array_key_exists('TAXAMT', $request)?$request['TAXAMT']:0;
$SHIPPINGAMT = array_key_exists('SHIPPINGAMT', $request)?$request['SHIPPINGAMT']:0;
$request['ITEMAMT'] = $request['AMT'] - $TAXAMT - $SHIPPINGAMT;
```

Then go to function `callDoExpressCheckoutPayment()`

Add below code before :

**$response = $this->call(self::DO_EXPRESS_CHECKOUT_PAYMENT, $request);**

```
$TAXAMT = array_key_exists('TAXAMT', $request)?$request['TAXAMT']:0;
$SHIPPINGAMT = array_key_exists('SHIPPINGAMT', $request)?$request['SHIPPINGAMT']:0;
$request['AMT'] = $request['ITEMAMT'] + $TAXAMT + $SHIPPINGAMT;
```